# Error During Use of Event Bus in Master Detail app

Tags: sapui5

Error

[image]

I am getting Error while using Event Bus (Subscribe and Publish).

So when the application is loaded first time from the launchpad, below code works perfectly.

But when I go back to my launchpad and come again to the app it is not working.

Error Comes here:

```
this._oList.getBinding("items").refresh();
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post error message? That screenshot could be posted as text.

Comment: Hi @barbsan - I have added error message also

Comment: Your error message says that `this._oList.getBinding("items")` returned undefined.

Comment: but when I load it the first time, this works fine, When I go to the main launchpad page and come back to the app again. Then this issue comes up.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
onInit: function {
    var view = this.getView();
    view.addEventDelegate({
        onAfterShow: function (oEvent) {
            ...
            your code
            ...
        }
    }, view);
}
```